# Save / archive SKSpriteNode in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite, archive

For a while now i’ve been trawling the internet trying to find a way to save a SpriteNode (and all the children of the node) to ‘disk’ so when I exit my GameScene and then return, the sprites are exactly how I left them.

I don’t need to archive the whole scene, just one node (and the many children it has)

I work in SpriteKit and Swift.

Can anyone please point me at a tutorial or some documentation that explains how to do this??

Many thanks for your help!!!

regards
Adam.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the `SKSpriteNode` and all of its children using the `NSArchiver` and `UserDefaults`.

```
func save(node: SKSpriteNode){
    let key : String = "skspritenode"
    //First create a key that can be used to encode and decode your node.
    //Then reference NSKeyedArchiver, and UserDefaults.standard
    let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: node)
    //^This line turns the node into savable data^
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(savedData, forKey: key)
    //^This line saves your node^
}
```

So, whenever you want to save your node, just call the function `save(node: SKSpriteNodeToBeSaved)`. Then, you can retrieve the encoded node later and load it when the scene loads.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView){
    let key : String = "skspritenode"
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let savedNode = defaults.object(forKey: key) as? Data {
        let theNode  = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: savedNode) as! SKSpriteNode
        theNode.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 4, height: self.frame.height / 4)
        self.addChild(theNode)
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. It took me a while to figure it out too. Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

An `SKSpriteNode` is a very complex object. It is a lot of trouble to store the whole thing. Don't forget it has lots of properties, and some of the properties, like `physicsBody` has sub properties.

So what you want to do is not to store the whole node, but to store some information that can fully represent your node. For example, if the only thing in your node that can change is its color, then you just need to store its color. When you want to recreate your node, you just recreate it normally, then read the color you stored and set it.

Eventually, you need to end up with a "property list", which is an object that contains only types of values found in property lists, like `String`, `Int`, `Bool`, `Array`, `Dictionary` etc.

Since you did not mention the exact scenario, I will just do an example:

```
class SpriteInfo {
    let positionX: Double
    let positionY: Double
    let subnodes: [SpriteInfo]

    // init here...
}
```

The above is a property list type. You can then store this in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: thank you for that, my node has possibly hundreds of other nodes as children and i need to save all of them, including size, shape, x/y position, angle relative to previous node...  and some other details.   Is there not a way to simply archive the whole thing using codable or some kind of encoding?  I guess redrawing the whole 'tree' could be possible, but seems like a painful way to do it...

Comment: Using codable is ok, but you still have to encode all those properties. Saving the entire state of a sprite node is not trivial. Maybe you are approaching the problem wrongly. @Adam

Comment: There is a way to save all of them without saving each variable and property separately using NSArchiver. Although your method would work, it is time consuming, space consuming, and tedious, especially for a task where you have hundreds of nodes to save.